# Just this puzzle (notes on the fridge)

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, english

Found some notes scrawled on the fridge. What was I struggling with?

> Anger? Bother? Chafe?
>
> Destroy? Eradicate? Forget?
>
> Garden? Herb? Ingredient?
>
> Just this puzzle?

Word tag - the answer is a word or set of words.

Bonus Question/Hint (for a creative thinker; this is optional but I'd be curious to see your creation):

> Write out (a close approximation or example of) what I specifically saw which caused me to write down these notes. (The answer is a word or set of words which describes this thing).

Hint 2:

> 'this puzzle' = 'K', but only numerically. Your best bet is to disregard the A-J pattern completely and think about other clues.

Hint 3:

> If you cook often, the 'garden herb' is probably on your spice rack.

Hint 4:

> Removed the no-computers restriction, as a computer won't [help](https://www.google.com/search?q=common%20herbs) that much anyway.

Hint 5:

> Line 1 could just as easily have been "Madden? Upset?"

Hint 6:

> [@VarunW](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/115633/78801) and [@blackjack_sparrow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/115638/78801) have spotted the relevant facts, but their conclusion is not logical. Imagine if *you* were trying to find synonyms for 'Just'. Your notes wouldn't look like this!

Hint 7:

> Throwing spaghetti at the blockquote may eventually work but will take forever. There is an easier way. Think logically about the question which was actually asked. Do *you* have notes on your desk that look something like mine (in certain ways)?

Hint 8:

> Abe Lincoln was reading a book on economics and wrote a note to himself: 'every economist should read this book'. Years later, historian buff Bob saw the note printed in Lincoln's biography and thinking Lincoln a sage, bought fifty more copies of the biography and mailed them to economists.

Hint 9:

> The easiest way to solve this puzzle is to follow a specific three step order. I thought the steps were fairly straightforward and logical but it seems everyone is stumped. You can solve it by skipping steps, but it will be more difficult. So I will give away Step One.
>  Step One: Focus on the title, intro, and tag. Take them at face value, there is nothing complicated going on. This step can be completed without even reading the blockquote. Step one is given in the tag:
>  [image: tag text]

Comment: Just a thought I've been playing with - I can't get past the fact these resemble rot13(pbzzba bar-jbeq pebffjbeq pyhrf gb guerr-yrggre jbeqf: VER, NQB, EHO, ZNE, EVQ, ???, YBG, EHR, OVG...) but I can think of no way to develop this further, so it's probably a non-starter. (Except that rot13(cyrnfvatyl, fbzr nccrne nf fhofgevatf bs pbhagevrf bs gur jbeyq ortvaavat jvgu gur pyhrq yrggre: oneoNQBf, qraZNEx...))

Comment: @Stiv You have the one 3 letter word correct! Your approach is similar to brute force which is viable... but there is also a simpler way. There is another pattern no one has yet called out .

Comment: rot13(Gur bgure jbeq V pbafvqrerq jnf VEX, juvpu znl jryy fngvfsl nyy bs yvar 1. Naq V'ir gevrq snfuvbavat gurz vagb n jbeq fdhner, juvpu unfa'g lrg obear sehvg.) Not quite spotting it yet! Maybe it will click at some stage... PS And huh, the effect of rot-13'ing that word is interesting...

Comment: @Stiv I guess the question is, do I sit and watch everyone suffer and hope someone eventually realizes in a glorious breakthrough that they were actually... boy it is so tempting to just say it...

Comment: @Amoz If there is a pattern couldn't you put the [pattern] tag?

Comment: @VarunW. I think this puzzle is more about logical reasoning.

Comment: @Amoz rot13(V abgvprq gung gur jbeq "Punsr" fcryyf bhg "N purs" vs cynprq pbeerpgyl. Nz V va gur evtug genpx?)

Comment: @VarunW. No, the specific words don't matter, think bigger picture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were struggling with something like

> My prefix will make you mad.
>  My infix does away with me.
>  My suffix is a flavorful plant
>  My whole is just what you see.

Which clues

> Rile Rid Dill

Or

> [Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6324/what-is-a-riley-riddle), which is just this puzzle.

Comment: Nice, this must be it

Comment: How in the world did you get that?

Comment: Wow, nicely done. I had to google rot13(evyrl evqqyr) because I didn't know what that was. Never would have gotten this one.

Comment: Wow same, this was a deep cut. For the curious https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6324/what-is-a-riley-riddle

Comment: @superhawk610 thank you, I've added that link to the answer.

Comment: Great job, glad this is solved! I'd thought the term was more well known as I've seen it in the 'recent' feed several times over the last few months, but in any case one thing I love about PSE is I am always learning new things. So many puzzles I see solved and realize 'I never could have solved that'... but I will next time! ; )

Comment: op notes: rot13(Uvag 8 jnf vagraqrq gb pyhr gur pbeerpg vagrecergngvba bs 'guvf', zrnavat gung V unq orra jbexvat ba n chmmyr, naq gurersber guvf vf hygvzngryl n dhrfgvba bs [erirefr-chmmyvat] (Fgrc 2). Gur N-W jnf cevznevyl nrfgurgvp, naq gb inthryl uvag gung gur nafjre jnf na 11 (X) yrggre flabalz bs 'guvf chmmyr', ohg vg zbfgyl whfg guerj crbcyr bss naq cebonoyl jnf haarrqrq.)

Answer (score 5):

For a short story-based approach, how about this?  You're struggling with...

> Jumbled Kids' Letters.

I feel your pain.

> You head home from work.  It's been a long day.  You pick the kids up from daycare on the way back to the house.  Finally get home, and you need to make supper.  Maybe the kids are going to be all chill and happy?  Nope.  It's screaming time.  But you still have to make supper.

So off to the fridge you go.

> You're dredging the dark depths of your mind to figure out what to cook that someone will actually eat.  Is it dinosaur nuggets again?  Do you have enough ketchup?  You start to open the fridge, but it's covered in colorful magnetic letters.  You can't seem to think straight with them all mixed up, so you start to put them in order.  You even come up with some words to match.

> Dang.  You're feeling a little angry at yourself for letting this tiny mess bother you.  No, that's too harsh.  More like it chafes you a little.  Whatever.  Get back on task.

> You're starving.  Gonna destroy some nuggets.  Maybe with barbeque sauce instead of ketchup.  Might even get wild and grab some mayo ... your thoughts trail off ... eradicate is a synonym for destroy.  You might be able to turn this into a decent puzzle.  Wait.  You forgot what you were doing.  Back to cooking supper.

> Is there anything fresh from the garden?  Maybe some herbs?  You're clearly out of your mind.  It doesn't take any ingredients to make nuggets.  They wouldn't eat anything green anyway.  Except peas maybe.

> What the heck?!  Where are all the other letters?!  You've only got a "J" left.  The rest must all be kicked under the fridge or stuffed down the vents or scattered out in the yard for some reason, never to be seen again.  You only have A through J.  Man, that's a bummer.

Oh, well.

> It was enough for just this puzzle.

Comment: Very creative! But other than by this very creative story, I am not seeing those specific words clued by the puzzle, or a likely thing I would struggle with. Hopefully you concur.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree!  I was just trying to entertain myself.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> Findings the synonyms of "Just" with a beginning letter of K and L.

Pattern I noticed:

> The capital letters spell out ABC, DEF, GHI and J.

> The rows belong to the same family.

> ABC -> Annoy; DEF -> Delete; GHI -> Groceries

Logic:

> Each row consists a word with its synonyms written across in an alphabetic order.

Anger? Bother? Chafe?

Destroy? Eradicate? Forget?

Garden? Herb? Ingredient?

Just this puzzle?

Comment: These are valid observations but not the final answer.

Comment: Btw other than getting distracted by the alphabetization, this answer is on track and nearest to completion.  Think carefully about the big picture.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

What were you struggling with?

> Just this puzzle!

**Reasoning**

Hint 7:

> "Do you have notes on your desk that look something like mine (in certain ways)?" I certainly do - I have those *exact* notes on my desk, after spending the better part of an hour I probably should have been asleep trying to solve this puzzle ;)

Hint 5:

> 'Line 1 could just as easily been "Madden? Upset?"' Depending on how you went about solving this puzzle, you may have written down various synonyms for the words given in the clue.

Bonus question:

> "Write out...what I specifically saw which caused me to write down these notes" You saw this post, or more specifically you saw your computer screen displaying this post. The chicken-egg problem here is explained by the fact that the question isn't a true story (or you really committed to the bit and wrote out these notes after submitting the question, kudos to you if so).

I don't know, maybe

> this answer is way too meta :) Either way, I enjoyed trying to think it all through!

Comment: This is the correct type of reasoning (this is not a cryptography puzzle or something) and certainly the second best possible answer to the puzzle. However there is a much more logical and obviously correct answer which does not require mind-bending thought experiments, and also explains the other features of the puzzle. For example, JustThisPuzzle!=K, and why herbs? But you are very close.

Comment: When trying to answer a puzzle try to emphasis your answer line by line or break it down by how you solved it. The reason we post answers it so anyone can see the answers and see how to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> Finding related words to "just" that begin with the letters "K" and "L"?

Reasoning:

> As @Varun W. said, the first letters of each word, except for the last two, spell out ABC, DEF, GHI, J. Additionally, each of the first three groups have words with similar or related meanings. For that pattern to continue, the words after "just" would have related meanings, and begin with "K" and "L". Since that didn't happen, that must be what you were struggling with.

Comment: Do you mean "K" and "L"?

Comment: The word tag means that the answer is a word or set of words which is demonstrably unique. This almost works but kl is not a relevant word and I suspect looking for k l words is a dead end.

Comment: @Amoz The wiki for the 'word' tag doesn't actually say anything about uniqueness - most word puzzles have unique solutions, but there are some that might not (at least from my understanding)

Comment: I included that to make it clear that my understanding is that any puzzle on this site should have a single solution, otherwise it gets closed as a open ended/etc. Maybe I am incorrect but in any case the goal of this particular puzzle is to find an obvious single solution, e.g. not "king because it starts with K". (as other words start with K), as a puzzle with several different choices for the word seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

> Kava Kava

Reasoning

*Word tag - the answer is a word or set of words.*

> Kava Kava is a word or set of words.
>  It is used for stress relief and memory. This fits the words described.

*Bonus Question/Hint (for a creative thinker; this is optional but I'd be curious to see your creation):*

> You saw Kava Kava on the shelf and were thinking about the benefits of Kava which are Group 1: Stress Relief, Group 2: Improving Memory, and Group 3: A description of an herb

> More specifically, maybe you were thinking:
>  
>  *Anger? Bother? Chafe?*
>  Will it help me with stress?
>  Alt: (If expired) Angry it expired. Why should I bother? I'm so vexed about this.
>  
>  *Destroy? Eradicate? Forget?*
>  Will it help me with memory?
>  Alt: (If expired) Should I destroy it? How did I forget about it?
>  
>  *Garden? Herb? Ingredient?*
>  Can I get this from my garden? Is it an herb for cooking? Can I use it in my tea?
>  Alt: (If expired) Do I have any more in my garden? Do I have any similar herbs? What ingredients could I use to have a similar effect?

Hint 2:

> *'this puzzle' = 'K', but only numerically.*
>  Kava Kava stars with K as the next letter in the sequence (the words all start with a letter of the alphabet, ABCDEFGHI, and K comes next)

Hint 3:

> *If you cook often, the 'garden herb' is probably on your spice rack.*
>  Kava Kava could be on your spice rack

Comment: Good try but the answer has a little to do with 11 (K is the 11th letter) but nothing to do with the letter K itself.